# Keeping files in treeview, but having troubles with taking them out

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

So, i have a c# windows form.
I put root directory with files to a TreeView

```
public void ProcessDirectory(string targetDirectory)
    {
        DirectoryInfo x = new DirectoryInfo(targetDirectory);
        treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(ProcessFiles(x));
    }

    private static TreeNode ProcessFiles(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
    {
        var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name);
        foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
            directoryNode.Nodes.Add(ProcessFiles(directory));
        foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
            directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));
        return directoryNode;
    }
```

And they display fine.
But then i try to delete them.

```
private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ((TreeView)sender).SelectedNode = e.Node;
    }

    private void deleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = ((TreeView)sender).SelectedNode.FullPath;
        FileInfo temp = new FileInfo(path);
        File.Delete(temp.Name);
    }
```

And it crashes when i try to convert Node to File.
I think i lose the path to original root in process and that causes the problem, but i dont know how to prevent this. If in adding function i use "FullName" instead of just "Name" program shows full path of every displayed file, but when i try to turn them into a FileInfo variable it still crashes.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really add `FileInfo` objects directly as `Nodes`. The constructor expects a `string` and you can't cast that Node back to `FileInfo` from that `string`..

I suggest adding the `FileInfo` to the `Node.Tag` property:

```
foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
{
    TreeNode node = directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));
    node.Tag = file;
}
```

Now to delete one you can access the FileInfo like this:

```
FileInfo FI = someNode.Tag as FileInfo;
```

Make sure it is valid and then process:

```
if (FI != null)         
{
   // do your thing
}
```